# How to Read Mongodb log number ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, debian

So i have a log at ubuntu server that i implemented logrotate to rotate the log, but i notice one things that the number is too big and i dont understand how to read the number beside the log
[image]

Any help on this? or any explanation to how to read it "52548376" or what does it stand for

here is my configuration for logrotate:

```
/var/log/mongodb/*.log{
   rotate 7
   daily
   size 100M
   missingok
   create 0600 mongodb mongodb
   delaycompress
   compress
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
     /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(pgrep -f mongod)
   endscript
}
```

i notice that it should rotate the log after it reached 100MB

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the file size in Bytes.

52548376 Bytes are 52MByte but you set a limit of 100MByte, so why do you expect a log rotation?

Instead of `kill -SIGUSR1 $(pgrep -f mongod)` I would suggest

```
kill -SIGUSR1 $( /usr/sbin/pidof mongod )
```

or even better

```
if /usr/sbin/pidof -s mongod > /dev/null ; then kill -USR1 $( /usr/sbin/pidof mongod ) ; fi
```

You specified `daily` which means the logfile is rotated daily, no matter whether the size reached 100MB or not. Using `daily` and `size` makes only sense if you run `logrotate` more than once a day.

Option `create` is not needed. mongod creates a new logfile automatically. Instead I would add `notifempty`

Comment: okay i got it now, but can i make it to hourly instead of daily?....

Comment: Do you really like to rotate the logfile every hour? This would save the logs only for 8 hours. Imagine you have a problem at night time. Anyway, you can create a hourly cron job where you execute `logrotate --force`

Comment: maybe one last question, which one is the most safest.., using it daily or set it to hourly clear log, and what does the log impacted to my application on the debian server

Comment: and i am not really understand what did you mean by this... "Using daily and size makes only sense if you run logrotate more than once a day." does it means my logrotate will be running more than once a day because of the limit or any..

Comment: What do you mean by safest? What do you like to get?